# Initial lag when starting Android App

Tags: java, android, xml, imageview, lag

I'm working on a chess type app for the Android platform (using Eclipse and standard Java / XML connection).  This isn't for school or anything, just a personal project after learning some of the fundamentals to "get my feet wet."

Anyway, my question isn't due to a direct problem, more to what I've viewing when I open the emulator and what I see in the logcat.

Generally, when I hit run for any app, the emulator takes its standard time loading it, but when it does, the main activity loads right away.  However, for this app, I'm experiencing a lag after the app loads, and when I quickly glance over to the logcat, it shows a TON of orange messages being generated...and then it displays my board (the app atm is just displaying a board).

Here is the HUGE logcat activity (sorry about the pastebin, but I'm new to this site and was having difficulty formatting this properly): http://pastebin.com/skc8SXqN

And here are my xml and java files: http://pastebin.com/8ByBQ0TA

My question is...is there any obvious reason for why the ~5 second lag occurs between the app loading and the board showing up?  The incredibly large logcat output is all directed to the imageview...so am I doing something heinously inefficient there?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you should be supplying a drawable for the `squareView.setImageResource()` whereas you are supplying `R.id.square_background` which does not seem to correspond to a drawable resource.

Answer (score 0):

Because here i seee you are referencing huge number of images in your project its normal for android emulator to slowdown your loading time of app.you can run it on device it will faster than the emulator..and put your image resources in `drawable` folder and reference them properly.

Answer (score 0):

As you stated, it was in the general vicinity of the way I was handling the image array...namely, I didn't need it at all.

The getCount() method, if I set it returning a total number of squares I wanted, would simply cause create the square X times without using an image array.

Changed that and voila, no lag.

this is resolved entirely!